# Error finding dependencies in Anaconda environment when running Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My code was previously working and this error has started occurring. I'm activating my anaconda environment, opening my jupyter notebook, and then this occurs in the first cell of my Jupyter notebook when I import sklearn.

`Could not find module 'C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\environmentname\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.UGR6EUQPIWHQH7SL62IWIXB5545VDNQZ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.`

The weird thing is when I follow this file path, this fortran dll file is in that folder where its supposed to be, so I'm not sure why this error is occurring. Any help is appreciated, please let me know if I can give more information to make it easier to help. thank you

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem and solved it by downgrading Scipy to version 1.6.1. You can do it with `conda install scipy=1.6.1`

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed any modules? If so, I'd try `conda update scipy`. Or `conda update scikit-learn`

Answer (score 1):

It works! Downgrading scipy to version 1.6.1 was the only way through which I stopped getting any error.

It takes several minutes to downgrade the scipy version by using the command:

> conda install scipy=1.6.1

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue after some update. I rebooted my PC and it worked again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).